# How to do I with missing dlls like msvcp100.dll, msvcp100.dll?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

How do I deal with this situation where the user's machine may not have dll like msvcp100.dll, msvcp100.dll? I don't want to my software not install on user's machine because this kind of error. I've been thinking in either find a tool and copy every single needed dll to the executable file run or try build a [static version of Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW) (may have sort of same result, in the end). I've seen applications that doesn't provide those dlls and it's up to user to get them, install etc. It may be a issue for those users, finding the right dll matching version and all. I'd like to avoid it.

How is this usually solved in a real world application?

Comment: I create a NSIS installer for each of my Qt applications and include the Visual Studio redristributable as an optional component of the install. Although my Qt builds are CMake based.

Answer (score 4):

You [redistribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx) them in your installer.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment of Qt apps is an **uneasy** issue. One should understand that you need to redistribute a compiler's dlls, as well as Qt dlls. For the **msvc 2010** compiler you may just put the `msvcp100.dll` and `msvcr100.dll` files near your executable file.
As for Qt, the easiest way for windows deployment is to use the `windeployqt` command prompt util.

**Update.** *How is this usually solved in real applications?*
**There is no fully automatic tools**, which could determine all the dependencies, because the deployment of applications is a complex task. For example, you application can depend on many things such as libraries dlls, compiler's dlls, registry keys, drivers, environment variables, computer reboot requirement, ActiveX/COM components, other installed applications, etc...
But there are tools that can help you in this matter. **They can be configured once** for target project and then work all the time. This is called **[Build Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation)**, another similar concept is a **[Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)**.
 **As for the creation installation packages for end users**, there is a lot of tools such as [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System), [Inno Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup), [Qt Installer Framework](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Installer-Framework), [WiX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX), etc...
[List of installation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software).

Comment: The dll I mentioned in the post are just example. I'm considering find a tool to do this job automatically. I was just looking to know how other people do it. I'm already using windeployqt but it doesn't copy those ms* dlls that I mentioned for example. Am I missing something or the util take care only of Qt's dlls?

Answer (score 0):

the installer script, put a command to download the dll that the application needs to run, and in the application source code, put it to use the dll's ONLY in the folder where it is running
If you are using the NSI installer, use this [example](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_can_I_download_files_from_the_Internet%3F/)